# pass the value of a checkbox to a state in React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to pass the value of the checkbox to the state cheked, I tended with the model below but it is not working. The standard value of the checkbox does not change, if anyone knows how to do it and can help me I am grateful.

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';

function Formulario(){
    const[cheked, setCheked] = useState(true)

    return(
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="checked" value={cheked} 
              onChange={e=>{setCheked(e.target.validationMessage)}}  />
            <label htmlFor="checked">cheked</label>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Formulario;
```

Comment: Use checked not value https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is create some sort of toggle. If you just set the state like this, you won't be able to toggle back and forth.

So what I would in this scenario is something like this

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';

function Formulario(){
    const[cheked, setCheked] = useState(true)

const handleChange = () => {

setCheckd(!checked)

console.log(checked)

}

    return(
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="checked" checked={cheked} 
              onChange={handleChange}  />
            <label htmlFor="checked">cheked</label>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Formulario;
```

So by doing so, the state is set to whatever is not equal to the checked value when there's a change.

I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Please set `e.target.checked` instead of `e.target.validationMessage`. Please check the below example:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

function Formulario() {
    const [checked, setChecked] = useState(true);

    return (
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="checked" value={checked}
                   onChange={e => {
                       setChecked(e.target.checked)
                   }}/>
            <label htmlFor="checked">checked</label>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Formulario;
```

Answer (score 0):

As lux pointed out, I think this is what you want:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checked" checked={cheked}
```

Using the **checked** attribute instead of the **value** attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Your event target validation message is most likely the problem , please implement the update below

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';

function Formulario(){
    const[cheked, setCheked] = useState(true)
    const handleInputChange=(event)=> {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.checked
    const name = target.name;

    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  }
    return(
     
        <div>
        <input
            name="isGoing"
            type="checkbox"
            checked={this.state.isGoing}
            onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
            <label htmlFor="checked">cheked</label>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Formulario;
```